# L'évolution du genre d’ « après-midi »

Tags: genre, régionalismes

L'Académie (et le Littré) donnent *après-midi* comme [un substantif féminin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/apr%C3%A8s-midi), et notent qu'il est parfois considéré comme masculin. Le [*TLF* donne les deux genres](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apr%C3%A8s-midi) (et des exemples de chaque). J'ai l'impression (dure à quantifier) qu'autour de moi, le masculin est plus utilisé. Quelqu'un a-t-il des données sur l'évolution du genre d'*après-midi* ? Est-ce que cela dépend des régions de la francophonie ?

Comment: L'académie semble avoir changé d'avis souvent en cours de route, contraste avec http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/apr%C3%A8s-midi (masculin) et http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/apr%C3%A8s-midi ("On doit préférer le masculin")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bon, je n'ai pas d'idée de la raison qui a conduit à cette évolution, mais l'évolution existe clairement et est attestée par un [Google ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5cJC.png)</sup> de “bel après-midi” vs “belle après-midi” :

[image: ngram]

Le masculin prend clairement une pente ascendante au tournant du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, pour dominer désormais le féminin dans la langue écrite. Je n'ai pas vraiment d'idée de pourquoi…

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5cJC.png) C'est un collègue qui m'a signalé que les ngrams marchaient aussi en français (je les utilise souvent sur [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Je n'ose pas imaginer à quoi le centre de traitement de données de Google ressemblait en 1800.